# Elements of the power set of $\textit{On}$ are elements of $\textit{On}$?

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

I don't know the truth value of this statement so this is just my own attempt.
I am attempting to prove this in NBG set theory.

Let $X \in \textit{P(On)}$ 
By the definition provided in my notes $X \in \textit{On}$ iff $X$ is well ordered by the $\in$-relation and is what my notes call 'full'.

Fullness is the property whenever $y \in X$ $\implies$ $y \subseteq X$

Assume $0\neq X$ since if $0 = X\in \textit{P(On)}$  $\implies X\in \textit{On}$ follows trivially.

So $0\neq X \in \textit{P(On)}$

First to show fullness:

It is taken as a proven theorem that $X$ is full iff $\ \bigcup{X} \subseteq X$

Let $y \in \bigcup{X}$ $\implies y\in z$ for some $z \in X$

Since $X \in \textit{P(On)}$ $\implies$ $X\subseteq \textit{On}$

So $z \in X \subseteq \textit{On} \implies z\in \textit{On}$

It is an established fact in my notes that $\textit{On}$ is full $\implies$

$y \in z \subseteq \textit{On}$ $\implies y\in \textit{On}$

So $y \subseteq z \in X \implies y \in X$ (!!!)

I'll stop here since I am uncertain about the validity of the final step.

This would allegedly prove the fullness of $X$. 
Well ordering would follow easily from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to be uncertain: that last step doesn't work.  There's no reason that $y\subseteq z\in X$ should imply $y\in X$.

In fact, it is not true that every element of $P(On)$ is full.  For instance, $\{\emptyset\}\in On$ so $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\in P(On)$, but $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is not full.

(Also, by the way, the standard term for "full" is "transitive".)

Comment: Just a general question. Does $y \subseteq z \in X \implies y \in X$ if we know $X,y,z \in On$ ? Since On is well ordered by the elementhood relation.

Comment: Yes, it is true if you know everything is an ordinal.  Since $On$ is (strictly) totally ordered by $\in$, we must have either $y\in X$, $y=X$, or $X\in y$.  But if $X\in y$ then we get $X\in z\in X$, and if $y=X$ then $z\in X\subseteq z$ so $z\in z$.  Both of these conclusions violate the fact that $\in$ is a strict total order on $On$ (alternatively, they violate the axiom of regularity).